# How to reject BindingSource/List changes?

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

I'm populating a DataGridView in this way

```
BindingSource myBindingSource = new BindingSource();
myBindingSource.DataSource = populatedList;           //list filled using LINQ to Entities
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource;
```

When I modify a myDataGridView cell, modifies are applied to populatedList.
My form contains a button (Cancel) that should be able to reject changes made to populatedList.
I tried using suspendBinding and resumeBinding of myBindingSource but it's not working (look the Note [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.suspendbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
I'm looking for methods like DataTable.AcceptChanges() and DataTable.RejectChanges().
How can I resolve?